# SQL select a row X times and insert into new

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to migrate a bunch of data from an old database to a new one, the old one used to just have the number of alarms that occurred on a single row. The new database inserts a new record for each alarm that occurs. Here is a basic version of how it might look. I want to select each row from Table 1 and insert the number of alarm values as new rows into Table 2.

Table 1:

```
|  Alarm ID    |  Alarm Value   |
|--------------|----------------|
|     1        |        3       |
|     2        |        2       |
```

Should go into the alarm table as the below values.

Table 2:

```
| Alarm New ID |  Value   |
|--------------|----------|
|     1        |    1     |
|     2        |    1     |
|     3        |    1     |
|     4        |    2     |
|     5        |    2     |
```

I want to create a select insert script that will do this, so the select statement will bring back the number of rows that appear in the "Value" column.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your sample data isn't making any sense to me at all.

Comment: I've changed the column names, hope it helps.

Comment: Note that it's problematic to use both the `Value` column, and store the instance-number as separate rows. What if you change the `Value` of Alarm 3 to 17?

Answer (score 4):

A recursive CTE can be  convenient for this:

```
with cte as (
      select id, alarm, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select id, alarm, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < alarm
     )
select row_number() over (order by id) as alarm_id, id as value
from cte
order by 1
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Note:  If your values do not exceed 100, then you can remove `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.

Comment: A few of the records are over 100, where do I need to add this?

Comment: Note: You have a typo in your SQL: `(max recursion 0)`instead of `(maxrecursion 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Replicate values out with a CTE.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(AlarmID INT, Value INT)
INSERT @T VALUES
(1,3),
(2,2)

;WITH ReplicateAmount AS
 (
    SELECT  AlarmID, Value FROM @T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT R.AlarmID, Value=(R.Value - 1)
    FROM ReplicateAmount R 
    INNER JOIN @T T ON R.AlarmID = T.AlarmID
    WHERE R.Value > 1
)

SELECT 
    AlarmID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY AlarmID), 
    Value = AlarmID --??
FROM
    ReplicateAmount 
ORDER BY 
    AlarmID
```

This answers your question. I would think the query below would be more useful, however, you did not include usage context.

```
SELECT 
    AlarmID,
    Value 
FROM
    ReplicateAmount 
ORDER BY 
    AlarmID
```

Comment: Never mind, I re-read your question and it seems the count of each alarm is tracked by it's occurrence in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an rCTE, which is recursive (as the name suggests) and will fail at 100 rows, you can use a Tally table, which tend to be far faster as well:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.AlarmID,T.I) AS AlarmNewID,
       V.AlarmID
FROM (VALUES(1,3),(2,2))V(AlarmID,AlarmValue)
     JOIN Tally T ON V.AlarmValue >= T.I;
```

Comment: This is a nice approach as well, however, I am guessing that tally stop returning results after a set amount of records 100,000? In SQL Server, recursion limit can be set to no limit.